# CakePHP : Manually set session ID?

Tags: session, cakephp

Is it possible to manually set session ID in CakePHP? I hope the question is straightforward enough.

Use case: For [Session-Id Header](https://www.w3.org/TR/WD-session-id)

Thanks.